# Android phone bluetooth connection to a bluetooth module

Tags: android, bluetooth

I want connect my app to a sensor with a bluetooth module. I paired phone bluetooth to module bluetooth. then Through Programming I create a connection with module. but I have a problem in Socket.connect() and not run line Socket.connect() and show toast ("c")

```
UUID uuid = UUID.fromString("00001101-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb"); //Standard SerialPortService ID
    try {
        mSocket = MyDevice.createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(uuid);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "S", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }  

    ba.cancelDiscovery();

    try {
        mSocket.connect();
    } catch (IOException e){
        Toast.makeText(this, "C", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    try {
        mOutputStream = mSocket.getOutputStream();
        mInputStream = mSocket.getInputStream();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "io", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Propably it cant connect beacuse your MyDevice is wrong. It have to be remote device not your device which one you use to listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord. You have to create

```
           BluetoothDevice  device = bluetoothadatper.getRemoteDevice();


public class AcceptThread10 extends Thread {
    private  final UUID MY_UUID = UUID.fromString("0125bb20-d629-11e3-9c1a-0800200c9a66");

      @Override
      public void run() {

       try {
           BluetoothServerSocket bluesocketserver = bluetoothAdapter.listenUsingRfcommWithServiceRecord(MY_UUID); 


           while (true) {


                 socket = bluesocketserver.accept();

                 socket12.close();

     }
```

Its only a part how it should looks you shoudl search for more in inteernet

Comment: I do not think MyDevice is wrong because I test my code with add MyDevice.getName() and show name remote device

Comment: What have you in logCat?

Comment: name of remote bluetooth device.

Comment: Meaby it cant connect coz your BluetoothServerSocket is bad? check if it listening and also UUID must be same

Comment: remote device is module bluetooth HC-05 and  I cant to programming BluetoothServerSocket. I use bluetooth setting in my mobile that paired two device. now I want get data from module bluetooth

Comment: Hmm i see. You thinking is wrong you MUST have bluetoothServerSocket to get data from BluetoothSocket. I will put how it should look in answer